# Sum of roots raised to the power 5

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If the roots of the equation $x^3-x+1=0$ are $a$, $b$ and $c$, then find the value of $a^5+b^5+c^5$.

**My attempt**:

I found out $a^2+b^2+c^2$ and a$^3+b^3+c^3$ but it is turning out to be extremely lengthy to find the sum of the roots raised to the $5^{th}$ power.

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Newton%27s_Sums

Comment: Have you tried using [Newton's formulas?](https://brilliant.org/wiki/newtons-identities/). Please also show us how you got the values of $a^2+b^2+c^2$ and $a^3+b^3+c^3$, so that we can better your thought process.

Comment: This should be tagged [tag:algebra-precalculus] rather than [tag:linear-algebra]

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: you are right! Done!

Comment: i used  the formulas a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^-ab-bc-ca) and (a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ca).I also used the concept of sum and product of roots and plugged in the values to get them

Comment: Multiply the equation by $x$ and substitute $x=a, b, c$ to get three equations and add these. Try and you will get the answer in this manner.

Comment: You should include your comments into the question as a part of your attempts.

Comment: Sorry for that!

Comment: Thanks, i got the answers without using newton's formulas!

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is a [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2317788/if-p-q-r-are-the-roots-of-x3-x1-0-what-is-p5-q5-r5). It is better to have only one version of the question so that all the answers can be collected in one place. See also this other exact [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2023584/let-a-b-c-be-the-roots-of-x3-x-1-0-find-a5-b5-c5) right here. Found using Approach0. If you can find the answer to the question using Approach0, you will get the answer quicker than if you ask a separate question.

Answer (score 3):

we have (use theory of equations) $$abc=1 ; ab+bc+ca=-1 ; a+b+c=0$$

now, $a^2+b^2+c^2=(a+b+c)^2-2(ab+bc+ca)=2$

also, as $a,b,c$ are the roots of the equation we have $$a^3=a-1;b^3=b-1;c^3=c-1$$
$a^5=a^3\cdot a^2=(a-1)\cdot a^2=a^3-a^2=a-1-a^2$ similarly for b & c

hence, $$a^5+b^5+c^5=(a+b+c)-3-(a^2+b^2+c^2)=-5$$

Comment: Isn't $abc=-1$ ?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$$x^3-x+1=0\implies x^5=x^3-x^2=-x^2+x-1.$$

Then

$$a^5+b^5+c^5=-(a^2+b^2+c^2)+(a+b+c)-3
\\=-(a+b+c)^2+2(ab+bc+ca)+(a+b+c)-3.$$

You finish with Vieta's identities.

Comment: Do you ever [search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24x%5E3-x%2B1%3D0%24%2C%20%24a%5E5%2Bb%5E5%2Bc%5E5%24&p=1)? I can understand if someone with 34 points does not know how, but...

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: I flag duplicates when I know they are.